# AlarmManager not working in service - Android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want to restart my service to fetch data from web server at particular time period (11 second) in my case. Thus, I've use `AlarmManager` to achieve this. but, somehow its not working.

I've added `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` `Broadcast Receiver`. that works fine.
When I start service from my `Activity`. it also start and works like charm.

here's my code

```
public class WalletConnectivityService extends Service {

    public static final String TAG = WalletConnectivityService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static boolean started = false;

    public static boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }

    /**
     * Factory Method
     */
    public static void start(Context context) {
        if (!isStarted()) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, WalletConnectivityService.class));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restart Service Interval
     */
    private static final int REPEAT_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 11 * 1000; // 11 Seconds

    /**
     * Variable for setting Alarm
     */
    private AlarmManager manager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private static boolean isAlarmSet = false;

    public static boolean isAlarmScheduled() {
        return isAlarmSet;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Alarm
     */
    private void setAlarm() {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, WalletConnectivityService.class), 0);
        manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), REPEAT_TIME_IN_SECONDS,
                pendingIntent);
        isAlarmSet = true;
    }

    /**
     * Cancels the Alarm
     */
    private void cancelAlarm() {
        if (pendingIntent != null && manager != null) {
            manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            pendingIntent.cancel();
            manager = null;
            pendingIntent = null;
        }
        isAlarmSet = false;
    }

    public WalletConnectivityService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        started = true;
        if (!Utils.isDeviceOnline(getApplicationContext())) {
            cancelAlarm();
            stopSelf();
        }

        if (!isAlarmScheduled()) {
            setAlarm();
        }

                    // AsyncTask will take place here to get data from web.

        started = false;
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        started = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, any luck with this? I'm trying to figure out the same thing.

Comment: @BaradiBaradari: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @BaradiBaradari follow the answer given by `qbix` or pass the `Broadcast Receiver` in `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `setAlarm()`, when you create `pendingIntent`, you must use [PendingIntent.getService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)), instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Comment: Thanks, Buddy. but, for the reason I was using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, I've done by passing simple `Broadcast Receiver` class in my app. but, Your answer is more proper solution than mine. Thanks for sharing this knowledge.